# How to run maven archetype generated struts 1 project in Tomcat?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, struts-1

I have copied my strutstest.war file to the webapps folder of Tomcat. Trying to launch it through `http://localhost:8080/strutstest`. But I am getting the HTTP 404 error. Should I include the Tomcat dependency in the pom.xml ? I don't know the artifactID though. Is there any vital point I am missing ?

**Update:**

My `struts-config.xml` contents given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
    <!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC
          "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.3//EN"
          "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-config_1_3.dtd">

<struts-config>
    <action-mappings>
        <action path="/HelloWorld"  type="com.test.HelloWorldAction">
            <forward name="success" path="/helloWorld.jsp"></forward>
        </action>
    </action-mappings>
</struts-config>
```

Comment: probably something is misconfigured in your struts application. you shouldn't have to add any tomcat dependencies to your maven project. can you share the Struts configs?

Answer (score 0):

Since your **Tomcat** is giving you a **404 page not found** it is clear that it works as intended. That message is there as a placeholder for **HTTP** errors.

And now getting back to your question, you should access any actions mapped if you want to get a valid **200 HTTP request** and for that please access the **URL** bellow:

```
http://localhost:8080/strutstest/HelloWorld
```

Assuming that your application is named strutstest the URL above should give you a **200 HTTP OK**.

**EDIT:**

Generally no matter what framework you are using you need to have an action mapped to an URL and only by accessing that URL you will get a valid request and response. Otherwise you will get a **404 Page Not Found**.